# Where did the Stack Overflow chat link go?

Tags: discussion, chat, footer

It seems as if with the updates to the Stack Overflow footer, SO also decided to remove the link to SO Chat. It's a long running joke in chat that Stack Exchange likes to pretend as if chat doesn't even exist. With all of the flags, the spam, and otherwise potentially inappropriate content that goes on in chat, I don't blame them.

Is this a possible step forward with killing the chat features? This bit is just an additional question based on speculation, but it's related due to the disappearance of the chat link.

**Edit**: People have made me aware that the chat link is also accessible through the Stack Exchange dropdown menu, but I was unaware that that icon was a menu; poor UX.

Comment: It's still available in the top bar, when expanding the Stack Exchange menu.

Comment: [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Regarding edit: they decided to put icons only, there's discussion already to set review icon back to text, you can ask to do the same with that drop down menu icon.

Comment: This is only applicable to SO, the other SE sites have it in the footer.

Comment: _“but I was unaware that that icon was a menu; poor UX”_ — related: [Too many hamburgers and not enough space for icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319224/289905).

Comment: What is so interesting about chat?

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the fact [Make the chat link one click away in the new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210095/new-header-chat-link)  was declined, without even giving any reason despite 20+ upvotes, I can say for certain that SE team indeed see no point in giving chat more visibility. They prefer to have it as kind of "hidden feature", used only by those who know it.

It does not mean they intend to kill chat, or discourage existing chat users from using it.

I can see the logic in this, and tend to agree: if chat will be too easy to reach, there is risk of low quality messages flood from new-ish users, who just gained their first 2 upvotes (2 on questions) and will want to get further help in the chat rooms.

With over 100 active rooms (real rooms, not imported comments or one-on-one rooms), I'd say chat on Stack Overflow is just fine and will still be fine with the chat  link removed from the footer.

Comment: Actually I disagree. As much as I love the chat, I'd rather noobs flood it with questions where they can get [potentially] live help, versus flooding the queue on Main, making it incredibly tedious to find good needle questions to answer in the hay stack of crap.

Comment: @SterlingArcher after asking enough bad questions, one get a question ban. That's not the case with chat.

Comment: I must disagree again, room owners can kick vamps (which we do after establishing vampage-trends). We have such cases where specific people simply are not allowed to chat anymore because they have been kicked so much. We have moderator authority to kick pest-users on sight. So far, it's worked rather well. Is that not a better alternative to a clogged main system?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to include a screenshot of this because your note is easy to miss.

> People have made me aware that the chat link is also accessible through the Stack Exchange dropdown menu, but I was unaware that that icon was a menu; poor UX.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I both missed the screen shot and never knew that the icon was a menu. Poor UX indeed.