# Where is the link to chat "on every page"?

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, help-center

Adjust the help pages for chat - there is no link on each page-footer any longer.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat

Text:

> **Where is chat?**
>
> There is a *link to chat in the footer* of every page, as well as *in the
>   Stack Exchange site switcher* menu (top right corner of the page). The
>   chat for this site is at:
>
> https://chat.stackoverflow.com

The other 2 ways are still valid (Site switcher menu, special link).

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com

Related [Where did the Stack Overflow chat link go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361536/where-did-the-stack-overflow-chat-link-go)

Comment: Or adjust the page footer to contain a link again :)