# Someone voted to close my post for it being opinion based, but how is it opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744228/how-does-graalvm-work-and-when-should-i-use-it) in question. After like 5 minutes of it being posted someone already voted to close my question for being *opinion-based*. How is this opinion based? I have questions with fixed answers!

All someone needs to do to answer this is be like: Yes, GraalVM should always be used. Yes, it compiles to machine language on each machine before it runs. It must be compiled and run with GraalVM to get the benefits. This isn't opinion-based!

Comment: Sorry, but just looking at the title makes it clear this should be closed. This definitely didn’t need 5 minutes to see. At the very least it should be closed for lacking focus, but the many questions for preference look impossible to answer without personal opinion.

Comment: "_Yes, GraalVM should always be used_" or the opposite is obviously an opinion... Note that "_Should I always develop with GraalVM?_" and "When should GraalVM be used" / "What are the benefits of using GraalVM compared to other JDKs" are quite different questions.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Well, I didn't know if my programs would perform better if I always used GraalVM to compile. I realize I need to split these kinds of questions up now. I edited it to just ask if I should always develop with it

Comment: @AnstonSorensen here's an example, the question: "Is XYZ the best programming language?" can have quite a straightforward Yes / No answer but it would regardless be an opinion. Similarly "_Should I always develop with GraalVM?_" is also opinion based.

Comment: What about _"Would always developing with GraalVM give higher performance?"_

Comment: @AnstonSorensen If that had been true, GraalVM would’ve seen more success, so there’s quite an obvious answer. ;) You’re probably wanting a detailed explanation, though, and that should be possible to provide in a non-opinion-based matter.

Comment: What version of GraalVM? Against what version of whatever you're comparing it against? On what platform? With what amount of memory? With what CPU? And once you've specified all that and more so that a comparison might be made, how much is that question worth when the next version comes out?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll add I'll that

Comment: I really wouldn't bother. The best you can do is turn the question from being closed as "opinion based" to being closed as "seeking recommendations"

Comment: That's not real optimistic. I suppose it would probably be better to ask all this on Reddit though

Comment: @AnstonSorensen Reddit, Discord, even Stack Overflow chat, all are better suited to this particular type op question (the type which invites opinion and discussion). But don't expect to be enlightened, you are asking a random bucket of strangers after all. This type of question is good for some entertaining discussion, not to be educated. If you want that... ask someone you know and trust. Better to have one grounded answers rather than a dozen ones that are all over the place.

Comment: Stack Overflow chat... Didn't know there was such a thing

Comment: Your question might be better suited to [SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) but do remember to read their [FAQs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) as your question will still need changing to meet their guidelines

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You asked at least three questions:

- When should I choose regular JDKs like Amazon Coretto over GraalVM.
- Would I always get benefits if I chose GraalVM over a normal JDK?
- Should I only choose GraalVM when I'm writing a more CPU or memory-intensive program?

and none of those are practical programming problems that have a definitive answer.

They might be interesting questions when you're brain-storming in front of a white-board or are in the midst of designing a system. And even then I would consider those questions discussion starters, not questions that get answered right off the bat.

As such the question as asked is too broad and the answers are deemed to be opinion based in the context of Stack Overflow. Note that there might be other sites within the SE network that take such question but if anything, they all take one at the time.

If you ask things like *Should I do X for case Y* you'll get much better answer if you ask: *I did X (include code, preferable an MCVE) for case Y and this is the result. I expected Z but that didn't happen. What is the reason for that and how can I get Z.*

Comment: This answer closely addresses the question. I noted that your reply didn't attack the question as invalid, only pointing out that it's out of the context of StackOverflow and why.

If "culture" is defined as a shared understanding, StackOverflow truly has a culture. When users are new, they don't have the shared understanding of the nuances of asking for an opinion. I think this is important because of my own experience of all the questions of my own that I have deleted, but still not understanding why they were considered asking for an opinion.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins yes, we have a steep learning curve and we should all be sorry  for that. Some progress has been made to inform users up-front and make on-boarding easier but it is far from ideal. If you have the option  / privilege to use chat then there are rooms where you can check upfront if a question would be on-topic. And although Meta can be rough sometimes most of us do try to help users that ask here about their question. If culture is a thing then it helps to expect the direct / Dutch / blunt approach.

Comment: I'm glad the issue is recognized. I once encouraged an 18-year-old who had a bit of coding experience to post a question about a problem, mostly to get experience in asking questions. He was so crushed by the replies, he won't go back and edit the question. But, it is true, I have noticed some improvements added to the UX. 

The option of putting a question in chat is a good one! Now, I will have to figure out where the chat function is.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins https://chat.stackoverflow.com/  and you're not the only one being confused by it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361536/where-did-the-stack-overflow-chat-link-go

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins If you can't find something, first place to look is in the *second* hamburger menu in the top bar, top-right :/ The one that does not look like a hamburger menu icon but actually me personally I would assume the icon is for a chat function.

Answer (score 5):

> How is this opinion based?

It's pretty straightforward. An [opinion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinion) is a judgment or appraisal. To say that one "should" or "should not" do something entails judging or appraising the action in question. Such statements are not objective.

If you can write the question without using words like "should" or "best" or the phrase "the right way to", then please do so.

If you can't, it almost certainly does not belong on Stack Overflow.

> I have questions

If you have questions, plural, then you have separate question posts, plural. This, too, is pretty straightforward. Only put them together if there is a compelling reason not to treat them separately.

> All someone needs to do to answer this is be like: Yes, GraalVM should always be used.

"Should" for what reason?

There are hardly any real no-brainers in programming. If it really were always correct to use tool X over tool Y, **you wouldn't know that tool Y existed**. Because nobody would be using it, and thus nobody would be talking about it.

If the question is "will GraalVM show a performance improvement in *my* program", the definitive way to answer this is to **try it**.

If the question is "will the performance improvement from GraalVM justify the effort involved in using it", only you can answer that question for yourself.

I can tell you these things even though I have literally never heard of this VM before in my life, because it's just the common sense of software engineers.

Comment: Yes; The question of performance might be the only question that could be answered but then you fall into the realm of needing to, perform benchmarks to answer it and ultimately those benchmarks are hardware dependent